# call $(this) on bootstrap multiselect

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I managed to show a bootstrap multiselect. I have a trouble.
When the select is closed, I hope I can call $( this ).

Help me please.

**EDIT:**

```
for (var akun in data_akun){
    $( '#select_akun'+data_akun[akun]['id'] ).multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        onDropdownHide: function(event) {
            alert( $(this).attr('current-attribute') );
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please, add some HTML...

Comment: Is there multiple elements with `select-multi1` id?

Comment: @Manoj actually, I use for-looping to call the $(selector).multiselect()

Comment: @Ukasyah Then you need to share whole code with for loop and html

Comment: When I inspect element on HTML, the selectors are exist just what I want.

Comment: where this `current-attribute` is associated with? Is it with `<select>` box and you wanted to access that?

Comment: could you please share your HTML and show us where exactly will be `current-attribute` present in DOM?

Comment: <select id='select_akun1' current-attribute='test'></select>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically in case of `onDropdownHide` we don't get the `element` reference directly. So to get it we can use following approach. Bootstrap `multiselect` generates its own DOM structure and styles the original `<select>` box. whatever DOM generated for display purpose get inserted around and next to original `<select>` box. Please use inspect element feature of browser's developer tool to check the generated DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.example-getting-started').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        onDropdownHide: function(event) {
            var selectObj = $(event.target).prev("select");
            alert( $(selectObj).attr('current-attribute') );
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<select class="example-getting-started" current-attribute='hello'>
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>

<select class="example-getting-started" current-attribute='world'>
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My bad. Thanks for your effort. It helps me so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this this will help you

```
for (var akun in data_akun){
    var $this = $( '#select_akun'+data_akun[akun]['id'] );
    $this.multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        onDropdownHide: function(event) {
            alert( $this.attr('current-attribute') );
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I need, Thank you very much.

Comment: This will not work I guess...the `alert` will show `current-attribute` of last select box present in for loop.

Comment: @vijayP This will work I have done it several times. you can test it in live case

Comment: @Manoj - you might be using similar kind of code with some other modification. Above code will not work as per requirement. Just imagine array contains 10 element. So these 10 `multiselect` will get initialized in 200 mili seconds and `$this` will get set to last select element. Now suppose after 1 min i did some interaction with my page and changed any selection in available select box. So now `onDropdownHide` will get invoked with `$this` pointing to last select and hence only its `current-attribute` will be shown.